# Naudio- Play double array

Tags: c#, arrays, double, naudio

I'm quite new to c# and I've been trying to write a program that would record sound, display it's wave, modify it and play it in real-time. Drawing graph works good because I used some examples from the internet for it, but I can't get the playback right. I've been trying to use "WaveOut" with double array converted to byte but it gives me some terrible noise but I think I can hear some things from my input. Thanks in advance!

Here are most important parts of code:

(Ys2 is array of doubles with samples)

```
    static byte[] GetBytesAlt(double[] values)
    {
        var result = new byte[values.Length * sizeof(double)];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(values, 0, result, 0, result.Length);
        return result;
    }
    public void UpdateAudioGraph()
    {
    [.....]
        WaveOut wo = new WaveOut();
        byte[] Ys3 = GetBytesAlt(Ys2);
        IWaveProvider provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(
                     new MemoryStream(Ys3), new WaveFormat());


       wo.Init(provider);
       wo.Play();
    [.....] 
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateAudioGraph();
    }
```

*EDIT

I managed to do that. There's still some echo but it works good. Here's the result:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static WaveFormat waveFormat;
    static int bufferMilliseconds;
    static int x = 0;
    public WaveIn wi;
    public BufferedWaveProvider bwp;
    public BufferedWaveProvider provider;
    public Int32 envelopeMax;
    public IWavePlayer wo;

    double cutoff = 10000;
    private int RATE = 44100; // sample rate of the sound card
    private int BUFFERSIZE = (int)Math.Pow(2, 16); // must be a multiple of 2
    //private int BUFFERSIZE = 44100;
    public byte[] frames;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // see what audio devices are available
        int devcount = WaveIn.DeviceCount;
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Device Count: {0}.", devcount);

        //waveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat.(RATE, 1);
        waveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(RATE, 1);
        bufferMilliseconds = (int)((double)BUFFERSIZE / (double)RATE * 1000.0);

        // get the WaveIn class started
        WaveIn wi = new WaveIn();
        wi.DeviceNumber = 0;
        wi.WaveFormat = waveFormat;
        wi.BufferMilliseconds = bufferMilliseconds;
        // create a wave buffer and start the recording
        wo = new DirectSoundOut();
        wi.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(wi_DataAvailable);
        bwp = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveFormat);
        bwp.BufferLength = BUFFERSIZE * 8;
        bwp.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;
        wi.StartRecording();
        wo.Init(bwp);
        wo.Play();
    }

    // adds data to the audio recording buffer
    void wi_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        int size = e.BytesRecorded;
        label3.Text = size.ToString();
        frames = new byte[size];
        e.Buffer.CopyTo(frames, 0);

        float[] values = new float[size / 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        { 
            values[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(frames, i * 4);
        }

        double[] doubleArray = Array.ConvertAll(values, x => (double)x);
        doubleArray = Butterworth(doubleArray,cutoff);
        values = Array.ConvertAll(doubleArray, y => (float)y);
        frames = values.SelectMany(value => BitConverter.GetBytes(value)).ToArray();

        x++;
        label2.Text = x.ToString();
        label1.Text = timer2.Interval.ToString();

        bwp.AddSamples(frames, 0, size);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing audio in doubles (presumably mono), but the playback code is expecting 16 bit stereo audio. If you can provide the audio as `float` then you can use `WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(44100,1)` (with the correct sample rate and channel count for your audio) in the constructor to `RawSourceWaveStream`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried to implement You advice, so I converted double array to float array and then to byte array and changed the provider, so it looks like that-  `code IWaveProvider provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(
                         new MemoryStream(Ys3), WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(44100, 1));in backticks` But the result is really weird. If microphone is silent, I hear some cracking and noise but when I speak, it's all silent. Additionally timer I use is 10ms.

Comment: You should not be opening and closing the soundcard every 10ms. Instead, use a `BufferedWaveProvider` feeding a single instance of `WaveOut`

Comment: Thanks for help! I finally managed to make it play microphone sound, but there's still one problem- it is very sliced. I tried to fix it by adjusting timer, so it's the same size as the buffer but the interval of "cut" is the same regardless the timer interval. I'd be very grateful if you'd like to help me, here's the code https://textuploader.com/dvoli

Comment: You should be using the same `WaveFormat` for the WaveIn and the output. So the `BufferedWaveProvider` should have `new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(RATE, 1);`

Comment: Finally I achieved some good results but to do that I used recording buffer for wo.Init() . I understand now that my problem lays in loading data to another buffer which is causing this breaks. It seems like there is some kind of de-sync but I don't know where is it coming from. Timer starts with the program and it's interval is equal to time needed to fill the buffer, so it should be OK. Here's the new code in case somebody would like to help https://textuploader.com/dv4kc

Comment: It seems  that even recalling `UpdateAudioGraph();` cause this breaks in buffer, because using `bwp` for  output when timer recalls it has got the same issues. I've got no idea how to solve it. I tried to run timer right after `wi` starts recording but it gave me no better result. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)